# Magento keeps redirecting to main domain

Tags: magento-1.8, redirect

We have two domains, one for the german shop and one for the shop in switzerland.

The urls are like:
    www.mycompany.de and www.mycompany.ch

But if I open www.mycompany.ch then I get redirected to www.mycompany.de!

What might be the cause?

Comment: contact your domain support, tell your issue.

Comment: You mean on first hit of your url it redirect to wrong url path?

Comment: Do you have two main domain or one is main and other is sub domain? Did you check to **core_config_data** table **web/unsecure/base_url** and **web/secure/base_url** path values? check also **app/etc/local.xml** if there is base path url value

Comment: @Hit's, both are main domains.

Comment: which step you follow to setup multi store with diffrent URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, we are using the Extension "Visitor Country IP Redirect" which redirects users according to their geo location.

We simply had to add our external IP on the whitelist at the configuration scope of the switzerland store.

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you sure that the config at each store level is set properly?
   i.e. each store had the correct setting for `base URL`?
2. Did you clear the cache and reindex?
3. [This is a great guide](https://docs.nexcess.net/article/how-to-configure-multiple-magento-storefronts.html) on setting up Magento multistore - they are two methods, follow all the steps and you should be set.

Comment: Yes, the base urls are all correct, I just checked it with `n98-magerun.phar sys:check`. The cache was cleared and the site was reindexed, made no difference.

Comment: The htaccess file is also correct, I checked if the storecode is passed to Mage::run correctly.

Comment: Where is this hosted

Comment: it is resolved now, lookup my answer.